# Confused about NFC tag size

Tags: android, nfc

I just started my NFC application and trying to **write read and delete** the content based on user action. I have few things which I am not able to understand.

**Regarding SIZE**

I have the tag where I have some data written. But when I am trying to write the same amount of data again on the same tag, I am not able to write it. Its giving the size more then max capacity. Is there some method coz of which its size is more or there is some other way to reduce the size.

**Regarding WIPING the data**

I also want to delete the data what ever I have written on the tag. Is there some way to wipe the data or I need to write empty string the way I am writing the data.

Can any body help me in this. Below is my code for writing the data

```
private boolean writeTag(Tag tag) 
    {
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(createNdefRecords());
        try
        {
            // see if tag is already NDEF formatted
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef != null) 
            {
                ndef.connect();
                if (!ndef.isWritable())
                {
                    displayMessage("Read-only tag.");
                    return false;
                }

                // work out how much space we need for the data
                int size = message.toByteArray().length;
                if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) 
                {
                    displayMessage("Tag doesn't have enough free space.");
                    return false;
                }

                ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
                displayMessage("Tag written successfully.");
                return true;
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            displayMessage("Failed to write tag");
        }

        return false;
    }

private void addTempData()
    {
        data.add("10");
        data.add("1");
        data.add("1");
        data.add("245");
        data.add("40238");
        data.add("0");  

    }

    public NdefRecord[] createNdefRecords()
    {
        NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = new NdefRecord[data.size()];
        for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            NdefRecord record  = getNdefRecord(data.get(i));
            ndefRecords[i] = record;
        }

        return ndefRecords;
    }

    private NdefRecord getNdefRecord(String data)
    {
        NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, MimeType.TYPE.substring(1).getBytes(), new byte[] {}, data.getBytes());

        return record;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have NFC tags that are writable?

Comment: How did you verify that the data in your code should fit on the tag? You defined 6 records, each of which has it's own header according to your choosen record type and MIME type. This needs space in addition to the net data which you want to store.  

Have you crosschecked with the header definition in the NDEF specs?  See: [link](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/), e.g. NFCForum-TS-RTD_1.0 and NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0

Comment: @Robert Ya that is writable. I can say that coz if I am inserting few data then that is reflected in tag and when I read the tag, I get the data what I had inserted

Comment: @corvairjo I got your point. I am novice in NFC and just started my first app. What I understand from your comment is I need to use single header and insert the data so that header does not occupy extra space. Can you provide me a sample code to achieve that. I am going through your  link.

Comment: How you partition your data into records is up to your app and the needs you have. You just need to be aware that each record has a header which also takes up space on the tag.    You don't need to create the header yourself, this is done by the OS when you create a NDEF record via the NdefRecord constructor or methods like createMime(String mimeType, byte[] mimeData).

Comment: But when I am creating createMime its taking more space then usual

Comment: @BlackDevil can you please suggest how to erase a tag messaegs?

Answer (score -1):

Look at this. [Write Tag](https://github.com/MoraisIgor/NFC_Wrapper/blob/master/code/src/com/hollowsoft/library/nfcwrapper/controller/tag/TagWriterController.java)

This is my NFC library. You can use this, if you need. :)

[NFC Wrapper](https://github.com/MoraisIgor/NFC_Wrapper)